# Apply CSS to "Theme Options" page ONLY in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My current PHP code is working and styling my "*Theme Options*" page (located under the WP API Appearance menu) the way I want it to look, however...

The CSS stylesheet is also being applied to every other menu in the WP dashboard (such as affecting the "Settings > General-Options") page too. How am I able to go about applying the stylesheet just to my "*Theme Options*" page only and not tamper with anything else?

My stylesheet is named 'theme-options.css", located within a folder called "include" > include/theme-options.css.  The code below is placed within a "theme-options.php" page.

```
<?php
// Add our CSS Styling
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'admin_enqueue_scripts' );
function admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-options', get_template_directory_uri() . '/include/theme-options.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-options', get_template_directory_uri() . '/include/theme-options.js' );   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was placing the CSS & JS files separately from the building blocks of my page (just above that function).  The code is now ***inside*** my page build function and I am now getting the results I was after.

Previously:

```
...
// Add our CSS Styling
function theme_admin_enqueue_scripts( $hook_suffix ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-options', get_template_directory_uri() . '/include/theme-options.css', false, '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-options', get_template_directory_uri() . '/include/theme-options.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );     

// Build our Page
function build_options_page() {

ob_start(); ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php screen_icon();?>

        <h2>Theme Options</h2>

        <form method="post" action="options.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        ...
        ...
```

Solution:

```
// Build our Page
function build_options_page() {

// Add our CSS Styling
wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-options', get_template_directory_uri() . '/include/theme-options.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-options', get_template_directory_uri() . '/include/theme-options.js' ); 

ob_start(); ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php screen_icon();?>

        <h2>Theme Options</h2>

        <form method="post" action="options.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        ...
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could only add the css file if the current page is your special page by [checking the page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) before, e.g.:

```
if (is_page('Theme Options')) { // check post_title, post_name or ID here
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'admin_enqueue_scripts' );
}
```

=== UPDATE ===

Maybe it is better to check in the function:

```
<?php
// Add our CSS Styling
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'admin_enqueue_scripts' );
function admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    if (is_page('Theme Options')) { // check post_title, post_name or ID here
        wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-options', get_template_directory_uri() . '/include/theme-options.css' );
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-options', get_template_directory_uri() . '/include/theme-options.js' );   
}
```

Comment: thank you for your fast response and from that, I've found my solution.